# removing a single item from localstorage with react, typescript, redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using rest countries api to fetch all countries, and i am suppose to add any country to favourite page saving it in localstorage but i am having error adding and removing an item in the array in localstorage in the slice i created

here is my code

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import type { PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
type Country = {
  flags: {
    svg: string;
  };
  name: {
    common: string;
  };
  region: string;
  capital: string[];
  population: number;
};

interface initials {
  post: Country[];
  postNumber: number;
}

const temp = localStorage.getItem("postItem");
const tempNumber = localStorage.getItem("postNumber");
const initialState: initials = {
  post: temp ? JSON.parse(temp) : [],
  postNumber: tempNumber ? JSON.parse(tempNumber) : 0,
};

export const postSlice = createSlice({
  name: "Post",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToFavourite: (state, action: PayloadAction<Country>) => {
      state.post.push(action.payload), (state.postNumber += 1);

      localStorage.setItem("postItem", JSON.stringify(state.post));
      localStorage.setItem("postNumber", JSON.stringify(state.postNumber));
    },

    removeFavourite: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      const postId = action.payload;
      const removeItem = (state.post = state.post.filter(
        (post) => post.name.common !== postId,
      ));
      state.post = removeItem;

      localStorage.setItem("postItem", JSON.stringify(state.post));
    },
  },
});

export const { addToFavourite, removeFavourite } = postSlice.actions;

export default postSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
localStorage.removeItem('postItem');
```

In the parameter give the name of your key, that is used when store data

Comment: It's removing all the items in the localstorage, i am trying to remove a single item without affecting the other items

Comment: @clemonezeh do you mean you want to keep `postItem`, but change the object it stores, so that the object has part of the object removed?

Comment: @Nathan yes  that is what i want

Comment: @clemonezeh the terminology you're using is wrong-- items in local storage are 1 key, you're referring to a single item (an object). What you want to do is read it from local storage, copy the object and remove the part of it you don't want, and store the new object back into local storage.